# vscode cd to workspace folder

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

The normal behavior of `cd` is to is to go back to `$HOME`. When in the vscode terminal I would like `cd` to take me to the workspace root. I do not want to use a hotkey or just open another terminal.

As if:

```
~/path/to/workspace $ cd /tmp
/tmp $ cd foo
/tmp/foo $ cd
~/path/to/workspace $
```

---

Related: A [How to change the terminal to the current directory in visual studio code ? (hotkey) [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668151/how-to-change-the-terminal-to-the-current-directory-in-visual-studio-code-hot) is closed as a dupe of a question I am not asking<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>"How to quickly change shell folder to match the currently open file". The current file is not the workspace folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set an environment variable when an integrated terminal is launched and use it in an alias of `cd`.

vscode `settings.json`:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux":  {"VSCODE_WS": "${workspaceFolder}"},
"terminal.integrated.env.windows":{"VSCODE_WS": "${workspaceFolder}"},
```

`.bashrc`:

```bsh
# Make `cd` from a vscode terminal go to the workspace root
# Assume the following is in vscode settings:
# "terminal.integrated.env.linux":  {"VSCODE_WS": "${workspaceFolder}"},
# "terminal.integrated.env.windows":{"VSCODE_WS": "${workspaceFolder}"},
# When in filemode / not in a workspace, `VSCODE_WS` is set to the literal `${workspaceFolder}` so we check and ignore that
if [[ -v VSCODE_WS ]] && [[ "$VSCODE_WS" != '${workspaceFolder}' ]]; then
    alias cd="HOME=\"${VSCODE_WS}\" cd"
fi
```

Works with gitbash too.

I have not tested with multiple folder workspace windows.

Comment: arguably even more convenient: `${fileDirname}` ([ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference))